# 2 Way communication between a parent and multiple children in C using pipes

Tags: c, linux

I'm having a problem trying to make my pipes communicate properly.
 Any help would be greatly appreciated. In a for loop I have the setup:

```
else if (pid == 0) { //child
    close(pipes[i][TOCHILD][1]);
    dup2(pipes[i][TOCHILD][0], 0);
    close(pipes[i][TOCHILD][0]);
    close(pipes[i][FROMCHILD][0]);
    dup2(pipes[i][FROMCHILD][1], 1);
    close(pipes[i][FROMCHILD][1]);
    //exec
    ...
    execvp(args[0], args);
    exit(0);
} else { //parent
    close(pipes[i][TOCHILD][0]);
    dup2(pipes[i][TOCHILD][1], 1);
    close(pipes[i][TOCHILD][1]);
    close(pipes[i][FROMCHILD][1]);
    dup2(pipes[i][FROMCHILD][0], 0);
    close(pipes[i][FROMCHILD][0]);
}
```

Then I have how I am trying to read:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++) {
    char buff[10];
    read(pipes[i][FROMCHILD][0], buff, sizeof(buff));
    fprintf(stderr, "read %s\n", buff);
}
```

And in the child I'm sending this for now:

```
printf("!");
fflush(stdout);
```

Comment: I want my stdout of the parent to be going to the terminal still but I think it is going to the children though

Comment: That comment should be in the question.

Comment: If you want to keep the standard output of the parent going to the terminal, you can't afford to redirect the pipe it will write to the parent's standard output.  You have to keep it as a separate file descriptor.  Similarly, the parent can't afford to redirect its standard input to each of the children's pipe in turn — you need to keep that as a separate file descriptor too. You should probably (nominally) use `STDIN_FILENO` and `STDOUT_FILENO` instead of `0` and `1` for the second argument to `dup2()`.  You should close the unused descriptors, as you do — that's good.

Comment: You should normally use `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` (or a more specific exit code) if you fail to `execvp()`.  It is good that you exit; it is not good that you exit reporting success.

Comment: FWIW: your children should send a more informative message, such as their process ID — and I'd probably terminate the message with a newline, though there are some grounds for not doing so.  That will enable you to check which child sent you which message.  As it stands, only the last child could send you a message because you are busy closing the read end of the other children's standard output with your `dup2()` to standard input.